# How to delete a tag on cloned git repository?

Tags: git, github

I have cloned an existing repository with a tag v1.1.

I see now the same tag v1.1 on the cloned rep (which still maintains an up-stream to the former rep).
But the cloned rep should really be v1.0.  How can I delete that tag to create v1.0 tag instead?

```
git tag
```

> v1.1

Then I tried this

```
git push origin :v1.1
```

I get the error message:

```
error: unable to delete 'v1.1': remote ref does not exist
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/xxx/xxx.git'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before deleting 1.1, you might want to tag that as 1.0 first.

```
git checkout v1.1
git tag v1.0             #tag release. use git tag -d v1.0 if v1.0 exists.
git push origin v1.0     #push tag to origin
```

Assuming you have access to the remote repository at origin, you can remove the tag with:

```
git push origin :refs/tags/v1.1  #remove remote copy of tag
git tag -d v1.1                  #remove local copy of tag
```

I'm a bit surprised your syntax didn't work. You should make sure your remotes are configured correctly, and that the tags exist on the remote you're pushing to.

Comment: It is enough to say e.g.`git tag v1.0 v1.1`